# How to return partial doc from Elasticsearch query/filter?

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I have a set of docs (let's call them `books`), which have a subset of information (let's say `editions`), for a data structure somewhat akin to this:

```js
"book": {
    "author": "A. N. Author",
    "title": "Fantastic Queries and How to Index Them"
    "editions": [
        {
          "publisher":"penguin",
          "isbn": 124161256653,
          "coverArtist":"Pain T Brush",
          "amazonPrice":65.50
        },
        {
          "publisher":"orbit",
          "isbn": 124163526653,
          "coverArtist":"Pain T Brush",
          "amazonPrice":25.99
        },
        {
          "publisher":"tor",
          "isbn": 124169876353,
          "coverArtist":"Pen See Il",
          "amazonPrice":700.00
        }
    ]
}
```

Right now with the queries I have (which search on `editions.publisher` or `editions.isbn`), I get the whole document back, including editions that don't match the query results. So, to be clear, if I search `coverArtist` for `Pain T Brush`, the data I want returned is:

```js
"book": {
    "author": "A. N. Author",
    "title": "Fantastic Queries and How to Index Them"
    "editions": [
        {
          "publisher":"penguin",
          "isbn": 124161256653,
          "coverArtist":"Pain T Brush",
          "amazonPrice":65.50
        },
        {
          "publisher":"orbit",
          "isbn": 124163526653,
          "coverArtist":"Pain T Brush",
          "amazonPrice":25.99
        }
    ]
}
```

Same with the other queries. If I search for a specific `isbn`, I only want its data to come back. If I set a price range of `> 500`, I'd only want the last edition (along with the author and title information, of course). And finally, if I search for `Fantastic Queries and How to Index Them` in the `title`, I want the whole doc returned, with all edition information, since I didn't specify anything edition-specific.

I'm unaware of a way to make the queries 'drill down' into particular objects in a doc, so is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the edition object into its own document, with a parent-child relationship.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html

This way you will be able to query for the exact child documents you need. If you also need the parent, each child document has a `_parent` property, which you can use in an `_id` search to return the parent doc.

You will still even be able to find the parent based on child attributes.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/has-child.html

Comment: Will it return both the parent object as well as the relevant child docs when I perform a has-child search? That page doesn't specify what it returns.

Comment: I'm not sure. Why not do a quick experiment and see? Worst case is that you can do two searches to get both of the documents you need: the parent and the children.

Comment: I did a test, unfortunately none of the queries get both the parent and child object. However, if the query returns the child, it inevitably has the `_parent` property, which I can use in an `_id` search to return the parent doc, so that should suffice. I'll accept your answer, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. I've updated the answer with your findings.